# Mysql Stored Procedure - get rows from multiple database tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get rows from multiple database tables in one of the database stored procedure in mysql.

Is this possible?

Please can you give me example about this.

```
     CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_procedure`(IN uid_user int)
     BEGIN
      select ucgm_id from `conne`.conn_group_membership where uid=uid_user;
      END
```

Comment: Yes, use i.e. joins or subselects.

Comment: I try to get just single row from other database table but it shows error in mysql workbench.

Comment: I updated question with procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursors can take data from multiple tables, and you can use them in procedures.

Comment: Please can you give me example for the same.